# Angular.js $compile doesn`t working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angularjs-bootstrap

I try to change all input type dates in project to uib-picker-popup, I use directive and $compile but new element doesn`t work. When I put result html to new .html its working fine, I guess there is some problem with $compile.

Source html

```
<input type="date" ng-model="picker" />
```

Directive

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('input', function ($compile) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      compile: function (tElem, tAttr) {
        if (tAttr.type !== 'date') {
          return;
        }

        return function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var ngModel   = elm.attr('ng-model');
            var name      = elm.attr('name');
            var className = elm.attr('class');
            var newElement = '<input type="text" class="' + className + '" ng-model="' + ngModel + '" name="' + name + '" uib-datepicker-popup is-open="isOpen">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isOpen = true">+</button>';
            elm.replaceWith($compile(newElement)(scope));
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Result html

```
<input type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-touched" ng-model="picker" name="undefined" uib-datepicker-popup="" is-open="isOpen" style="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="isOpen = true">+</button>
```

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZoTsbAMVSINZYIqsrfE?p=preview)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it and it works:

```
var newElement = '<div><input type="text" class="' + className + '" ng-model="' + ngModel + '" name="' + name + '" uib-datepicker-popup is-open="isOpen">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="isOpen = true">+</button></div>';
elm.replaceWith($compile(newElement)(scope));
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JPSpVyWgDJeC0NtNhnib?p=preview